# Parse Separate Numbers from string (Regex)

Tags: regex, parsing

I want to have a function where I can parse numbers out as well as dashes (-) and dots(.).How can I do this with regex?

Comment: Example: PRINCE DRAGON 12
         2 NE RABIL. 12
         COBO NE.12

Comment: [By trying.](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Could you at least specify what you need to do with the `PRINCE DRAGON 12 2 NE RABIL. 12 COBO NE.12` string?

Answer (score 0):

which language you are using ? but generally
to parse (.)dots and dashes(-) just use \ (backslash) before them so regex will take them as search terms instead of its own parameters.